# PHP SQL query very slow

Tags: php, sql, oracle

This line makes the query run very slow. If I remove the " + K.OFFSET/1440" section it runs fine. Is there a faster way to do this?  $From_Date = "02/04/2014" and $To_Date = "05/04/2014".

```
AND (CT.START_GMT + K.OFFSET/1440 >= TO_DATE('$From_Date', 'mm/dd/yyyy')) AND (CT.START_GMT + K.OFFSET/1440 <= TO_DATE('$To_Date', 'mm/dd/yyyy'))";
```

Comment: Please tell us the complete Query.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you add, subtract, or apply a function to a column to a column being used in:

- A field in a `WHERE` clause
- A field inside the `ON` for a join

You loose the benefit of any index that's on it.

The `START_GMT` column was probably part of an index which is no longer being applied.

You can Compare the index use of the query before and after adding the addition with  and see if index usage has changed.

```
 explain <your fast query>;
 explain <your slow query>;
```

You'll most likely see the 'possible_keys' and the 'Extra' column changing between the 2 explain queries if the key issue is the issue.

If you move the addition to the other side of the comparison, you'll get  back the index benefit:

```
  (CT.START_GMT  >= TO_DATE('$From_Date', 'mm/dd/yyyy') - K.OFFSET/1440) AND ...
```

Do this on all your comparisons in your where clause.  Good Luck!